# Some strange phenomena in my use of np.array() to creat a N*M array

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I use the for Statement and some api supported by pandas to load some files, I created a list of temporary data and finally created an array with the list data, This array can be created as I typed a few files at a time, but when I import multiple files, I create a strange array. Ensure that all files are the same number of columns and rows. What should I do?

Py3.6, the latest pandas

when i load few files a times

```py
import numpy as np
dirList=os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder\SecData\renzaorou\sec20190527')
priceList=[]
for i in dirList[:3]:  # few files
for i in dirList: # all files
    print(i)
    df=pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\New folder\\SecData\\renzaorou\\sec20190527\\'+i)
#     row_price = df['price'].tolist()
#     print(df)
#     break
    priceList.append(df['price'].tolist())


np_price=np.array(priceList)
```

the expected output when i load few files

```
array([[ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  6.32,  6.32,  6.32],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ...,  3.45,  3.45,  3.45],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , ..., 11.51, 11.51, 11.51]])
```

then when i load all files

```
array([list([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.1.........
```

i expect the Normal output when i load all files

Comment: Look at `priceList`.  Is it the expected list of lists?  Are all the sublists the same length?  My guess is `np_price` is a 1d array with object dtype.  If the lists differ in size, it can't create a 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need to append numpy arrays to your list. Try that:

```
import numpy as np
dirList=os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder\SecData\renzaorou\sec20190527')
priceList=[]
for i in dirList: # all files
    print(i)
    df=pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\New folder\\SecData\\renzaorou\\sec20190527\\'+i)
    priceList.append(df['price'].values)


np_price=np.array(priceList)
```

In case the `price` column is not numeric, just replace

```
priceList.append(df['price'].values)
```

with

```
priceList.append(pd.to_numeric(df['price']).values)
```